# question about hausdorff distance

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $ 0 \leq u_n \leq 1$ a sequence of smooth functions defined in a bounded open domain $\Omega$. Supoose that $u_{n+1} \leq u_n$. Fix $l \in (0,1)$ and consider the level sets $A_n = \{ x \in  \Omega  \ ;  \  u_{n}(x) = l \}$ and $A  = \{ x \in  \Omega  \ ;  \  u(x) = l \}$, where $ u = lim  \ u_n$ .

I am studying the proof of a theorem . If I prove

$$ A_n \rightarrow A$$
in the Hausdorff sense, then I understand a important part of the theorem. Someone can give me a help tp prove the affirmation above ?

My idea: The function $u$ is continuous in the compact set A. By the monotonicity condition of $u_n$ , we have $u_n \rightarrow u$ uniformly in $A$. I stopped here ...

Comment: The sets need not converge. Consider for example $u_n(x) = l + \frac{1}{n+k}$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is chosen large enough that $u_0 \leqslant 1$. Then $A_n = \varnothing$, but $A = \Omega$. Either you don't need convergence in the Hausdorff distance, or there are some additional constraints that guarantee that convergence.